# What exactly is a critical point, and what is the relevance of the rank of the Jacobian?

Tags: curves, jacobian, singularity, inverse-function-theorem

### Definition

Taken from Wikipedia, the definition of critical points I am used to:

Given a differentiable map $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^m$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$, the critical points of $f$ are the points of $\mathbb{R}^m$, where the rank of the Jacobian matrix of $f$ is not maximal.

I understand this to mean that at a critical point $c \in \mathbb{R}^m$, the derivative $df_c$ is not surjective.

---

### Current understanding

I am used to critical point meaning points in the domain of a single-variable function $f(x)$ where the derivative is zero, and I am struggling to understand the generalisation to multiple variables.

I am particularly struggling with the surjectivity condition. I have seen that surjectivity allows us to "trim" columns of the jacobian and obtain an invertible matrix, which along with the inverse function theorem gives us the implicit function theorem:
given a continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and a non-critical point $p\in\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$, we can recover the level set $f^{-1}(0)$ in a neighbourhood of $p$ as ($\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})$), where $\mathbf{x}$ is $n$ suitable coordinates of $P$.

### My question

What exactly breaks down when $df_p$ is not surjective ? Do we lack the information for a suitable linear approximation at p ? Why does the lack of surjectivity tell us something "funny" is happening at $p$ ?

[image: singular point]

(singular point at (0, 0) of the algebraic curve $y^2-x^3-x^2=0$)

In the above graph, the problem to me seems to be one of injectivity: there are several directions in which $y^2-x^3-x^2$ remains zero.

Comment: In the single variable case the critical points have derivative of zero, which is a zero dimensional space rather than a one dimensional space. The multivariable case is the same with the determinant of the Jacobian being zero at the critical points, which is equivalent to the Jacobian having a non-trivial nullspace, which is in turn equivalent to the map not being surjective. So in both cases we're examining the zeroes of the derivative in a meaningful way but in the multivariable case we have more conditions that are equivalent to this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see those conditions are equivalent. So why are we examining points where the derivative has non-trivial null space ? Is there any intuition as to why this leads to more "odd" behaviour, such as the curve intersecting itself above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ in your question is $f(x,y)=y^2-x^3-x^2$ from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ and its Jacobian is the (transpose of the) gradient
$$
(\partial_x f, \partial_y f)=\big(-3x^2-2x,\,2y\,\big)\,.
$$
As a linear map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ this is not surjective if and only if it is $(0,0)$, in other words, in $(x,y)=(0,0)$ where the curve defined by
$$
f(x,y)=0
$$
intersects with itself.

- ***Intuitively*** this happens because a traveller following the curve stays on the level set all the time, and at the critical point has the choice to switch to one of the two branches of the self-intersecting curve.
- At any other point there is a unique direction the traveller has to follow if he or she wants to stay on the level set (curve) because the directional derivative is zero only in that unique direction.
- Work out the relationship between gradient and directional derivative to dive into this. Also (hint): how many orthogonal vectors to the gradient exist at a non-critical resp. at the critical point ?

Comment: The gradient is a vector whose entries are the directional derivatives along the arguments of $f$. It points in the direction of greatest increase of $f$, and vectors orthogonal to the gradient point in the direction of 0 derivative.  In our case at non-singular points there is one (2-1) direction orthogonal to the gradient. In the general case $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, the Jacobian is made up of n gradients giving the direction of greatest increase of the $n$ components of the image of $f$.

Comment: The number of orthogonal directions giving non-zero change is the rank of the Jacobian, or the dimension of the vector space spanned by the gradients (i.e. directions not orthogonal to all gradients at once). Therefore the number of directions giving 0 increase is $m$ minus the rank of the Jacobian.
In a nutshell, at singular points, there are more orthogonal directions of zero increase than at non-singular points, which make up the (vast) majority.
Is this a fair account ? Thanks again for your answer

Comment: Yes that sounds good.